# What alcohol beverage goes well with a certain type of smoking?

Tags: taste, recommendations

Some beverages go well with different foods.  White wine with fish, red wine with ... Is there such a thing as beverage and smokes combinations that suit the taste buds?  For example, beer with certain types of cigarettes or cigars; what kind of difference would there be and how would I aim to please?  The specific smokes I had in mind are the different cigarettes, cigars.  The most simple combination that came to my mind is coffee and a cigarette.  But I'm interested in alcoholic beverages and smokes.

Comment: Marijuana is legal in some parts of the world. Would  marijuana pairing be permitted?

Comment: Whisky and cigars

Comment: @user6035379 I have proposed a Cigars SE. You might be interested in it as there seems to be no other SE site where questions about smokes are on topic. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/104111/cigars-and-other-smokes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Smoke and drink like a pirate.

> **Rum** and **cigars** both hail from the Caribbean, so it’s no coincidence that they work well with one another. Match the spiced and sweet molasses undertones of this full-bodied dark spirit with creamy cigar, like a flavorfully nutty and cocoa-infused [Casa Magna](https://www.jrcigars.com/brand/casa-magna). Yes, we know there are clear rums as well but, in all honesty, most combinations with this spirit will be subpar. - [Best Cigar Pairings with Beer & Alcohol Drinks](http://Best%20Cigar%20Pairings%20with%20Beer%20&%20Alcohol%20Drinks)

For those into **E-Cigarettes** here is a suggestion:

> A British e-cigarette manufacturer has a new option for those who enjoy a smoke with their favorite alcoholic beverage. London Fox recently rolled out two new e-cigarettes, the Silver and the Refresh, meant to be paired with beers, cocktails or wine. - [This E-Cigarette Offers Suggested Drink Pairings](http://www.psfk.com/2016/07/e-cigarette-offers-suggested-drink-pairings.html).

Here is some pairings for Marijuana, for those interested and where it is legal to smoke: [How To Pair Beer And Marijuana: A Match Made In Hazy Heaven](http://www.foodrepublic.com/2016/02/18/how-to-pair-beer-and-marijuana-a-match-made-in-hazy-heaven/).

Comment: I had totally forgotten about E-cigarettes.  It brought vaporizers to mind.  They have many flavors for vaporizers (is that what they call them)?

Comment: I have a vape (now I have two addictions!), and when I use the fruity flavored liquid, to be honest it tastes no different when 'vaped' than any other liquid.  And somehow it just doesn't quite 'cut' it 'do the job' of a sit down with a drink and a cigarette...

Answer (score 3):

A good cigar pairs well with a neat snifter of whiskey or aged bourbon. Tobacco is a naturally occurring plant, and whiskey is a byproduct of naturally occurring plants as well. What you’ll find is that each complements and enhances the flavors of the other. The flavors of the cigar will take on new, invigorated life, and the whiskey will offer you great flavors that would otherwise be too subtle without the discerning presence of the cigar.

[Beverages to Pair With Your Favorite Cigars](https://www.zindeed.com/articles/beverages-to-pair-with-your-favorite-cigars)

Comment: Excellent idea.  If I didn't already pick an answer I would have chosen yours.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that smoking diminishes one's ability to taste(I'm not sure about Vaping). I haven't found any literature that explains if just only one cigarette will change your sense of taste, but anecdotally I believe it will have an effect.

[Smokers' bitter taste buds may be on the fritz](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2014/03/140325094810.htm)

This a large reason that smoking and drinking often go together.  Alcohol tastes less potent to smokers.  As an obvious result, more potent liquors like moonshine or absinthe will go do down a little easier for smokers.

In my mind, the most classic pairing of smoke and alcohol is cognac or regular brandy and a cigar.  Often people dip their cigars into brandy before drinking.  Generally, this is considered a faux pas and unnecessary given modern humidors. The origin of this tradition was to add moisture to the cigar.  The dipping can take from the nature flavor of the cigar.  However, I recommend it for particularly cheap or unpalatable cigars, or if you don't like them at all but are smoking one anyway.  Be careful though, it can be a little like putting ketchup on Filet Mignon.

Nonetheless,  The flavor of cognac/ brandy compliments cigar smoking quite nicely.  You can sip them and enhance the flavors of the cigar.  My preference is Grand Mariner(made from cognac and bitter orange), and a cigar, although I am not cigar aficionado so I don't have a specific cigar to recommend.  The Grand Mariner flavor rests on the tongue after drinking and creates a very rich mouth feel, particularly in combination with smoke.

Vaping seems prime for pairing with alcohol.  Given the myriad flavors available, I think match flavors would be good.  Consider the vape juice flavor as an ingredient in your cocktail.  Jack and Coke? Try vanilla vape juice and it will be reminiscent of Vanilla Coke.  Try Cake Vape and Gingerale and Vodka to create the impression of Cream Soda.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of articles and blogs regarding [tobacco and beverage pairing.](http://pipesmagazine.com/blog/put-that-in-your-pipe/tobacco-and-beverage-pairings/) These usually focus on cigars and pipe tobacco. In general, pair tobacco to alcohol in the same way one would pair food and alcohol. Fruity food pairings = fruity tobacco pairings, etc. In theory, mentholated tobacco would go with any minty food/alcohol pairings (no experience with this one.)

Due to the mass-production of (and chemical additives in) most cigarettes, they are generally not considered. However, organic and artisan cigarettes can also achieve a nice pairing with some beverages. Personally, I enjoy a full-flavored, organic tobacco Natural American Spirit with a Guinness, when I can.

With Marijuana, these turned up in a quick search...

[Marijuana and wine pairings.](http://www.thecannabist.co/2015/05/01/wine-weed-guide-pairings-marijuana/33764/)

[Interview regarding Beer and hash pairing.](http://www.thecannabist.co/2015/03/04/craft-beer-hash-class-pairing-denver/31003/)

Comment: From my own recent research I have found that a sweet drink adds greatly to the smoking experience.  Examples of sweet drinks are easy to find.